# ReactJS - Passing Array to Imported Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to modularize my components into external files and import them into an index file, but I'm running into an error related to passing an array to an imported component. It doesn't appear to be handling this array in my modularized component and I'm wondering if it is an issue with my importation in my index file or with my component logic in the external file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import path from 'path';
import Comments from './comment/record-comment';

//Loop through JSON and create Record and Comment Container Component
const RecordFeed = props => {
    return (
        <div>
        { 
            props.records.map((record, index) => {
                return (
                    <RecordCard {...record} key={record.recordIdHash} user={props.user}>
                        { record.record_comments.map((comment, i) => 
                            <Comments {...comment} key={comment.recordCommentId} /> 
                        )}
                    </RecordCard>
                );
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**record-comment.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

//Record Comment - Comment
const Comment = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h5>{props.user_id}</h5>
            <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
            <h3>{props.app_user.fullNameSlug}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

//Record Comment - Container
export default class Comments extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Comment />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error being logged?

Comment: Can't see you importing `RecordCard`

Comment: Please import `RecordCard`. Why you are using `Comment` and `Comments `. Both are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to export `Comments` component which does nothing, export just the `Comment` component as `export default Comment`. If in any case (which i can't think of) you do require to export `Comments` class, make sure you pass props to the child like -

`export default class Comments extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Comment {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}`

Also, you don't seem to be importing your `RecordCard` component

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was a template to see if the import was working. I plan on building on this foundation with more modularized elements, which is why I have the two components. Also, `RecordCard` is set elsewhere in the `index.js` file. I didn't think it was relevant to the question which is why I left it out of the code. Will I need to define props somewhere in the code you mentioned above?

Comment: No. The `{...comments}` and `key` props you have provided in `index.js` will be provided to the stateful `Comments ` component as `this.props`.